# When using babel with nodemon, view is not updated when files are changed?

Tags: javascript, express, babeljs, nodemon

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel app.js -d dist",
    "start": "npm run build && nodemon dist/app.js"
  },
```

...

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9"
  }
```

**app.js**

```
import express from 'express';
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('World 1');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

When I run `npm start`

[image]

Browser output

[image]

When changes are made to the code, app restarts.

Here I made 'World 1' to 'World 2'

[image]

But when I refresh the browser it still shows World 1

If I do `npm start` again and rebuild, then the browser shows 'World 2'

How do I fix this?

[[example-node-server][4](https://github.com/babel/example-node-server)](https://github.com/babel/example-node-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"start": "nodemon dist/app.js --exec babel-node --presets babel-preset-env",
```

For babel to work with nodemon you start script should be as above.

Please go through [this](https://medium.com/developer-circles-lusaka/how-to-setup-express-js-server-with-nodemon-and-babel-c3a17218c282).

Comment: I was about to comment with same answer. You just answered 36 seconds ago. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that nodemon is running the built code while the build didn't occur after code changes. It is why you don't get updated.

You should consider running nodemon without the need to build while you are developing

`nodemon --exec babel-node lib/index.js`